# Typing 10 degree West

Tags: writing, numbers

When giving a location, e.g. 10 degree West, 20 degree North, I do not put any space between the number and the degree sign (correct, isn't it?). But what is to be placed between degree and N/S/E/W (in UK English, if there are differences)? For example, 10°W or 10° W or (TeXish) `10\degree\,W`, or what else?

Comment: This seems more like a formatting question than an English Language question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latitude) and [National Geographic](http://education.nationalgeographic.com/encyclopedia/latitude/), its used with spaces:

- "40° 26′ 46″ N 79° 58′ 56″ W"
- "23° 26' 21'' N. Its twin, the Tropic of Capricorn, is 23° 26' 21''
  S."

Comment: OK, the spaces in your answer are between `°` and minutes and beween `"` and quadrant, but for symmetry it makes sense to always place a space after degree here. (One might note that there is no space in `°C`.) National Geographic is from the US and not UK, but there does not seem to be a difference between US and UK English here. Thus: +1 and accepted!